# memorystream question

Tags: c#, .net

After write the xml document into the memory stream. When I want to use it by using XMLDocuments.Load, I have to set the position back to 0.

I am wondering If there any standard way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the simplest way is just:

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

I'm not sure what you're after beyond that. You *can* use the `Seek` method, but personally I find the `Position` property to be far simpler.

Do you definitely need to go via a stream in the first place? If you've already *got* the `XmlDocument`, why not just use that?

Comment: I am using XMLDocument.load to load a xml document from memory stream writtern by another module. So I have to set the memory stream position back to 0.

Comment: @user496949: Right, so you set `stream.Position` to 0 as per my answer. What else are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty much how you have to do it.  The position must be set back to 0, because after writing the document into the stream, the stream is positioned at the end, ready to append more data.  Setting the position to 0 effectively "rewinds" the stream, so that you will read it back in from the beginning.

This is a normal and expected usage pattern, if you are doing something like this anyway.